# isympy: Problems with indentation

Tags: python, emacs, sympy

I am running isympy within emacs shell (emacs 24, debian, snapshot)
I do not have much experience with Python!! The following is driving me nuts:

```
In [77]: k=0

In [78]: for i in range(3):
   ....: for j in range(3):
   ....:     if i <= j:
   ....:        for l in range(6):
   ....:            J[k,l] = diff(Y[i,j], vars[l])
   ....:        k = k+1
   ....:     else:
   ....:        pass
   ....:     continue
   ....:
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

(I have tried MANY variations on this!)

I do believe the code is correct, but isympy do not think so!!

¿What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `for`-loop needs to be indented from the first, so instead of

```
In [78]: for i in range(3):
   ....: for j in range(3):
```

have

```
In [78]: for i in range(3):
   ....:    for j in range(3):
```

Also, the

```
else:
   pass
```

doesn't really do anything and could be deleted. It's not clear that `continue` does much here either.

Another frequent culprit is an inadvertent mixture of blanks and tabs. [PEP 8 - The Style Guide for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends the use of [blanks for indentation over tabs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Comment: Finally, with your hints it worked, but only after setting %autoindent    OFF

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen glad I was able to help solve your problem. I suspect the use of autoindent and your own editing was probably mixing blanks with tabs.